# What is the difference between these two declaration of anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

I'm not able to find differences between these two declaration of anonymous class.

```
class Boo {
       Boo(String s) { }
       Boo() { }
    }
    class Bar extends Boo {
       Bar() { }
       Bar(String s) {super(s);}
       void zoo() {
           Boo f = new Boo() {                       // Line-1
               void method()
               {
                   System.out.println("Inside anonymous");
               }
           };
       }
    }
```

```
class Boo {
       Boo(String s) { }
       Boo() { }
    }
    class Bar extends Boo {
       Bar() { }
       Bar(String s) {super(s);}
       void zoo() {
           Boo f = new Boo("Random String") {         // Line-2
               void method()
               {
                   System.out.println("Inside anonymous");
               }
           };
       }
    }
```

Here what i understood is, anonymous class is subclass of class `Boo` whose instance is polymorphically referred by reference variable `f`. But what difference it makes in using no-args constructor (Line-1) and parametrized constructor (Line-2).

Comment: Not much if `Boo` is not doing anything in its constructors. Perhaps you should add some "meat" to the `Boo` constructors.

Comment: @RealSkeptic "Not much if Boo is not doing anything in its constructors" Can you elaborate on this plz by suggesting a scenario when it makes difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add some "meat" to your classes to see what the difference is. Change `Boo` so that it actually does something with the string:

```
class Boo {
    private String s = "Default";

    Boo(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    Boo() {
    }

    protected String getString() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Now it stores the string, and any subclass can retrieve that string via the `getString()` method.

Now expand our `Bar`:

```
class Bar extends Boo {
    Bar() {
    }

    Bar(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    void zoo() {
        Boo anon1 = new Boo() {                       // Line-1
            void method()
            {
                System.out.println("Inside anonymous");
            }
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "First anonymous subclass of Boo with value " + getString();
            }
        };
        Boo anon2 = new Boo("Some Random Value") {    // Line-2
            void method()
            {
                System.out.println("Inside anonymous");
            }
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Second anonymous subclass of Boo with value " + getString();
            }
        };
        System.out.println(anon1);
        System.out.println(anon2);
    }
}
```

So I created the two types of anonymous classes inside the same method, and then I print them. Note that I have added a `toString` method to each of the anonymous classes. And the `toString` method uses the `getString` from `Boo` in the value it returns.

Now, what happens when you call `new Bar().zoo()`?

You get the output

```
First anonymous subclass of Boo with value Default
Second anonymous subclass of Boo with value Some Random Value
```

So the first object, `anon1` is created with `Boo`'s no-args constructor. Therefore the private `s` has the value `Default`. This reflects in the `toString()` method. The second object is created with `Boo`'s other constructor, that gives `s` a different value. Now that value becomes part of the value printed.

So when the constructors actually do something, and the anonymous class makes use of the information that was passed in the constructor, then it makes a difference if you pass a parameter or not.

**Notes**

- `Bar` itself is also a subclass of `Boo` but in your example, it makes no difference. It could be a completely independent class.
- The method `method()` is never used and cannot be used (except with reflection etc.) because the only reference to the anonymous class is through type `Boo` which doesn't have an inheritable `method()`. You can't call a subclass's method from a superclass reference unless the method is inherited or overridden.

Comment: This makes complete sense.. :)

Answer (score 3):

- It notes that `Boo` have multiple constructors defined in it.

And

```
 Boo f = new Boo("Random String") {         // Line-2
               void method()
               {
                   System.out.println("Inside anonymous");
               }
           };
```

Since it is an annonymous class, and provided the implementation right away, there is no one using that  string  and that string passing is redundant there.

Comment: Means we can use any available constructor in creating anonymous class. that makes no difference?

Comment: We can use any constructor, if it available.